How can I use ISR in vercel without using the fetch function?
I am following this doc https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration to create ISR application. It says using fetch to cache the data in the doc. However, I have some cases that data is not from http server. Instead the data could be from database query, graphql server, etc.
My code is as below. The method fetchProductWithCache uses unstable_cache function to fetch data.
export const fetchProductWithCache = async (country?: Country) => {
  const product = await unstable_cache(
    async () => {
      let product = PRODUCT;

      if (country && PRODUCTS[country]) {
        product = PRODUCTS[country];
      }
      await setTimeout(() => {}, 1000);
      return Promise.resolve(product);
    },
    ['product'],
    { revalidate: 10, tags: ['product'] }
  )();
  return product;
};


export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
  // Get the list of countries
  const countries = await api.product.countries();
  console.log('generating static paths:', countries);
  return {
    paths: countries.map((country) => ({
      params: {
        country,
      },
    })),
    fallback: 'blocking',
  };
};

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<any, any> = async ({ params: { country } }) => {
  // Get product for country
  console.log('generating static data:', country);
  // const product = await api.product.fetch({ country });
  const product = await fetchProductWithCache(country);
  console.log('finish generating static data:', country);

  return {
    props: {
      country,
      product,
    },
    revalidate: 10,
  };
};

...

I got this error at build time. What could be wrong with the code?
Error: Invariant: incrementalCache missing in unstable_cache async


You can use unstable_cache
A quote from the doc:

If you are using an ORM or connecting to a database, you can use unstable_cache:

Sample code from the same doc:
import { unstable_cache } from 'next/cache'
import { db, posts } from '@/lib/db'
 
const getCachedPosts = unstable_cache(
  async () => {
    return await db.select().from(posts)
  },
  ['posts'],
  { revalidate: 3600, tags: ['posts'] }
)
 
export default async function Page() {
  let posts = getCachedPosts()
  // ...
}


Does it work at build time? I tried it but get Error: Invariant: incrementalCache missing in unstable_cache during build time

It's probably because you are using it in a client component. https://stackoverflow.com/a/78997435/23258247

I am using it on server side. I have posted the code in this post if you can have a look at.
